# Java unchecked conversion of arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, type-conversion, unchecked, unchecked-exception

Can anybody tell me how to create an array-arraylist the right way ?!

```
.\File.java:5: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
        ArrayList<myObjectType> myParkingLotArray[] = new ArrayList[3];
                                                 ^
  required: ArrayList<Vehicle>[]
  found:    ArrayList[]
1 warning
```

I want an arry (or any other solution) which stores 3 arraylists. How to add objects to the arrylists would be nice to know too.

ParentArray

1. ChildArrayList1
2. ChildArrayList2
3. ChildArrayList3

Im happy for any Help

**SOLUTION:**

```
public class myClass {
  ArrayList<myObjectType>[] myArryName= new ArrayList[3];

  public void addLists() {
    myArryName[0] =  new ArrayList<myObjectType>();
    myArryName[1] =  new ArrayList<myObjectType>();
    myArryName[2] =  new ArrayList<myObjectType>();
  }
}
```

The warning can be ignored or suppressed.

Answer (score 8):

You **can not** create an Array of classes that use generic types - see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays)!

And there is no way to work around that error message. The compiler tells you: this ain't possible!

Instead - simply stay with **one** concept. There is no point of mixing arrays and Lists anyway. Just go for

```
List<List<Vehicle>> parents = new ArrayList<>();
```

And then

```
List<Vehicle> someChild = new ArrayList<>();
```

To finally do something like

```
parents.add(someChild);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a cast

```
ArrayList<myObjectType>[] myParkingLotArray = (ArrayList<myObjectType>[]) new ArrayList[3];
```

However, I agree with GhostCat you should try to use arrays or lists but not mix them. a `List<List<myObjectype>>` would be better.

Comment: `ArrayList[] myParkingLotArray = new ArrayList[3];` this worked ?!

Comment: @2vkIYKaT4mNOMe0uRjtsoT5AF you can suppress the warning with `@SuppressWarning("checked")`

Comment: @2vkIYKaT4mNOMe0uRjtsoT5AF true, though you don't have a generic type anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create arrays of parameterized types.

What you can do insteade is the following:

```
List [] arrayOfLists = new ArrayList[10];
arrayOfLists[0] = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
```

but you **can't be sure** that all the lists will be List of the same type.

Otherwise you can use simply List of Lists in this way:

```
List<List<Vehicle>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<>();
List<Vehicle> list = new ArrayList<>();
listOfLists.add(list);
```